# How to download the latest Ubuntu repo and make it available locally in my PC offline?

Tags: repository, offline

I want to install Ubuntu in a PC with no internet access.

I want to have a local copy of the repositories in an external HD drive. This external HD drive is formatted as NTFS and has about 1 TB of free space.

How much space will I need to have a full copy of the repositories? Where and how do I download it? How do I set it up so that when I plug in the external HD, my PC sees it as the source repository?

**Update:** I have been reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository, and I downloaded all the files inside http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/ (binaries for architecture amd64). I think I've done something wrong, because it totals to only about 50 MB. Isn't it supposed to be around 50 GB?

Comment: @EliahKagan I've read other related answers on this site but they haven't helped. Where are the supposed 50GB worth of packages that I should download?

Comment: @EliahKagan Why is there a duplicate banner in my question then?

Comment: Reviewers: We should reopen this, because it is not asking how to ferry packages between repositories and offline machines; instead, it's asking how to create and use a complete local mirror. (We have questions that mention mirroring but as far as I can tell none have answers about how to do so.) **becko**: I retracted my close vote but others still thought this was answered in [that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/974/22949). I've voted to reopen this question. @muru Do you think this should remain closed? If not, Luis Alvarado might decide to reopen this (as he's the only other VTCer).

Comment: I too think this question should be opened. As @EliahKagan sayd, I am asking about all the steps required to download and mirror a local copy of the Ubuntu repositories (last version, trusty), stored either in the PC, or in an external HD drive.